# Automatically floating all fields in a VFP report?

Tags: report, foxpro, visual-foxpro

I want to set all the fields and labels on a `VFP7` report to `Float` and `Stretch with overflow`.  I tried Using the `.frx` file and doing the following `REPLACE` but it didn't work.

Is there some other field I need to change too?

```
REPLACE float WITH .T. FOR objtype = 8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out you have to set `top` to `.F.` for `float` to take effect, this worked:

```
USE report.frx
REPLACE float with .T., stretch with .T., top with .F. for objtype = 8
```